# Converting multiple .pdf files with multiple pages into 1 single .csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, tabula

I am trying to convert .pdf data to a spreadsheet. Based on some research, some guys recommended transforming it into csv first in order to avoid errors.

So, I made the below coding which is giving me:
**"TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type ''; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid"**

Error appears at 'pd.concat' command.

'''

```
import tabula
import pandas as pd
import glob


path = r'C:\Users\REC.AC'
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.pdf")
print (all_files)

df = pd.concat(tabula.read_pdf(f1) for f1 in all_files)
df.to_csv("output.csv", index = False)
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Since this might be a common issue, I am posting the solution I found.

"""

```
df = []

for f1 in all_files:
    df = pd.concat(tabula.read_pdf(f1))
```

"""

I believe that breaking the item iteration in two parts would generate the dataframe it needed and therefore would work.

Comment: So you changed "df = pd.concat(tabula.read_pdf(f1) for f1 in all_files)
" with "df = [] for f1 in all_files: df = pd.concat(tabula.read_pdf(f1))"? Because if I do that I get only one csv file but with only one of the pdf's parsed